# Tried FGLRX and other question's answers, graphics still not working right. (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I've tried every suggestion that I've looked at online. My card is a Radeon HD 4250. I've installed fglrx to no avail. After install I just either go into low graphics mode or it will detect my card as VESA: RS880 and none of my games will work that use 3D. I've done terminal install of fglrx and even used AMD's site, both of which do not work. I looked into jockey and Additional Drivers and it shows nothing. I'm not sure what's going on, but my old roommate had it working at one point. I did a fresh install and cannot figure out how to get it back to playing games.

I'd appreciate any help or anyone pointing me in the right direction. As I said, I've tried everything I can search so far and nothing has helped, hence the new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD has dropped support in their proprietary driver for that card. You have two options:

1. Uninstall fglrx drivers and use the open source radeon driver (Recommended)
2. Use the [AMD Catalyst Legacy](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) PPA

Note that for (2), your X server will be downgraded to support the older 13.1 fglrx driver. This could lead to other issues and comes with a load of caveats, so read the warnings carefully.

Comment: Quick question on that: Do I need to manually downgrade my X server or will it be automatic?

Comment: If you use the PPA, I believe it's automatic when you install fglrx-legacy, but again, read the directions and warnings carefully.

Comment: After install I got: Sorry, a problem occurred while installing software: fglrx-legacy. It gives me no other details. Should I go ahead with a reboot and see what happens or uninstall and try a different method?

Comment: If this is a fresh install of 12.04.3, you should note that fglrx-legacy is not supported; that may be reason for errors. I recommend uninstalling fglrx and fglrx-legacy and trying the open source radeon driver. More info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: I reverted back to my open source drivers but now it shows "Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880" and my games are working but extremely laggy.

Comment: You may want to consider upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 or at the very least install the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). That will give you a more recent version of the Gallium3d driver, which is much closer in performance to the proprietary driver.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Games seem to be running a lot better but still having some issues. I'm sure I can find a means to get them to a better performance but all in all your suggestion helped a lot!